# REWRITING - Exclude only php files

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I really need your help about mod_rewriting and conditions.

For my job, i have to make a simple rule for statics files.
If it's a static file, i just add a "statics/" in url.

I tried this:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)\.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)  /product/cerberep/sources/statics/$1 [L]
```

It works for:
- index.php?name=test
- js/test.js
But if I got another dot in th query string i got an 404 error. For example:
- index.php?file=test.js
As you can see this is a php file with another dot.

Can you help me to exclude only php files please :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to match against the query string at all here.

```
RewriteRule !\.php$ /product/cerberep/sources/statics%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work with it =/
I have a 500 internal error